# Recommendations needed for European short run photobook publisher

Tags: printing, service-recommendation, publishing, photobooks

I'm looking for a European publisher who can do (very) short run photobooks - hardback "Taschen" style is my brief and I have two clients lined up. I'm looking for something a bit different which isn't necessarily mass market like Blurb. I'm based in London so UK publishers would be ideal. I'm not after layflat or flushmount printing. Totally open to vanity publisher recommendations if the quality / service is appropriate.

Comment: Product recommendation questions tend to be off-topic here as answers may become incorrect over time, as new products/services are created and old ones expire.  You may get better answers directly in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat).

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, I'm still too green to post there. Looks like I'll have to build some reputation.

Comment: Have a +1 to help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

I used Photobook worldwide / Canada. They are printed in Malaysia.  They do a really nice job. You can either work online or download the software and work off-line. T hen you have to submit the finished pages online.